# optimizing buy and sell signals in R

Tags: r

I need to optimize the existing buy and sell signal same like backtrader in r.

**Signal** 
will be looking like

```
-1 -1 -1  1  1 1 1 -1 -1 -1  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

where **-1 = hold , 0= buy , 1=sell**

after optimizing signal should  be

```
-1 -1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

I just want to consider only first signal in a group of  buy and sell .
i want to reduce sequence of multiple buys and sell.

**EDITED- original question restored same like initial.**

can anyone help me? help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
signal[signal %in% 0:1 & c(NA, diff(signal)) == 0] <- -1
```

does the job. `signal %in% 0:1` finds buying and selling, while `c(NA, diff(signal)) == 0` looks for group elements other than the first ones.

If -1, 0, and 1 are the only possible values of `signal`, then, as @lmo suggests, simply

```
signal[c(NA, diff(signal)) == 0] <- -1
```

suffices as only additionally replaces -1 with -1. On the other hand, if `signal` is very long, those redundant replacements perhaps could take some extra time.

Comment: I tried in various possibilities and didn't work. This is working fine.. Thanks bro

Answer (score 4):

This should also work. Here, you check for differences in in the signal value and replace all values that have no change to -1. The initial FALSE pads the initial value.

```
z[c(FALSE, (diff(x) == 0))] <- -1
```

which returns

```
z
[1] -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

**data**

```
z <- scan(text="-1 -1 -1  1  1 1 1 -1 -1 -1  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0", what=0L)
```

Comment: hey bro @imo do you have any solution for scenario 2??

Comment: @Sarath_Mj I don't immediately see the difference between your new scenario and your initial one. My suggestion is to post a *new* question with a link to this one that explains the difference and how these answers don't work. You will definitely get more eyes on it that way. Also, please include a reproducible example, like the one in my answer. This will make it easier for others to focus on your problem rather than reconstructing the data.