# Buy and sell signal to be optimized in r

Tags: r

this question is [similar like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611942/optimizing-buy-and-sell-signals-in-r/49612099?noredirect=1#comment86233102_49612099) .. but this is quite different..

signal i'm getting like this

```
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 -1
 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 
 0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

say for example

if 0 comes then it has to wait until get 1 in between all values should be -1 , like wise it should be there.

it should be looking this..

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  -1 -1 -1  1  0  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1  0  -1
  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1  1  0  -1 -1  -1 -1 -1  1  -1  0  -1  -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  -1  -1  1
  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
```

It should be like **buy sell buy sell** like this..

help will be appreciated...

*request note - due to poor question frame, i could not ask new question. kindly add vote to lift the ban.

Comment: If I understand correctly your rules are: Keep the first 0 if its sequence of 0's is followed by a 1 set the other 0's to -1. If the sequence of 0's is followed by a -1 set all the 0's to -1. Are these rules correct and enough?

Comment: The English is not perfect but I do not think it deserves so many down-votes the problem is quite understandable and interesting to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for your transformation are : Keep the first 0 if its sequence of 0's is followed by a 1 set the other 0's to -1. If the sequence of 0's is followed by a -1 set all the 0's to -1

Which is equivalent to

Get rid of the -1's since they are not modified and does not impact the other values. Now our sequence only consists in 0's and 1's.
Then, set all 0's and 1's that follows an identical value to -1.

```
x[x!=-1][sequence(rle(as.character(x[x!=-1]))$lengths)!=1] = -1
```